# Highlighting and programming the Janus GridEx

Tags: c#-4.0, janus

I programming C#,but intermediate in Janus
I want the row that they have date values less than 5 days to specific date to be coloring.
how can do it?
(in GridEx ,Format Condition can not do this)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by suscribing to the GridEX.FormattingRow event. If the row contained in the event arguments meet your criteria, initialize the row's RowStyle property and customize the style as needed.

```
void gridEX1_FormattingRow(object sender, RowLoadEventArgs e)
{
    GridEXRow row = e.Row;

    // ... evaluate if the row meets your condition

    row.RowStyle = new GridEXFormatStyle();
    row.RowStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow; // Highlight the row
}
```